# Installing Postgres Binary - Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm trying to install Postgres with zip file because I don't have admin rights on this PC. I unziped to C:\Users\cs192056\AppData\pgsql\bin and then when I try to type the code below, the figure shows the error:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Translation: "A problem caused the program to stop working properly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Other information:
[image]

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you get that Postgres version from? I have never seen `initdb` when started from the command line to display any GUI dialogs

Comment: I got it from the Postgres website: https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries